# Intercept Save event in Word 'Save As' dialog

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

In Word, I have an open document - I navigate in the 'Save As' dialog to a directory and select an existing file. When I now click 'Save' instead of 'Cancel', I get the message if I want to overwrite/merge the existing document.

Is it possible to intercept the 'Save' event in the 'Save As' Dialog so that I can change the file name of the open document, suppressing the overwrite/merge message? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.beforesave.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is totally possible to intercept Word commands. In the VBA days, it was as easy as creating a macro with the same name as the internal Word command.

In VSTO, you need to add the command overwrite to your Ribbon XML and then add a callback to your code.

The entire procedure is described in MSDN: **[Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462633(v=office.12).aspx)**

**Sample Ribbon XML** (overwriting the standard Save command)

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" 
   onLoad="OnLoad" > 
   <commands> 
     <command idMso="FileSave" onAction="mySave" /> 
   </commands> 
   <ribbon startFromScratch="false"> 
     <tabs> 
       <tab id="tab1" label="Repurpose Command Demo" > 
         <group id="group1" label="Demo Group"> 
           <toggleButton id="togglebutton1"  
             imageMso="AcceptInvitation"  
             size="large"  
             label="Alter Built-ins"  
             onAction="changeRepurpose" /> 
         </group> 
       </tab> 
     </tabs> 
   </ribbon> 
</customUI>
```

**Ribbon Callback**

```
public void mySave(IRibbonControl control, bool cancelDefault)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The Save button has been temporarily repurposed.");
    cancelDefault = false;
}
```

Comment: I guess, you would also need to catch the Save event in case some one saves via CTRL+S or F12?

Comment: @PetLahev: That's already done -- the entine `FileSave` command is intercepted, not a single click somewhere in the Ribbon.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the Office dialog by your own like this

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z(v=vs.110).aspx

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.DocumentBeforeSave += Application_DocumentBeforeSave;

}    

void Application_DocumentBeforeSave(Word.Document Doc, ref bool SaveAsUI, ref bool Cancel)
{
    SaveFileDialog dgSave = new SaveFileDialog();
    dgSave.Title = "This is my save dialog";
    dgSave.FileName = "This is the initial name";
    dgSave.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Temp";
    dgSave.FileOk += dgSave_FileOk;
    DialogResult result = dgSave.ShowDialog();
}

void dgSave_FileOk(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var test = (SaveFileDialog)sender;
    MessageBox.Show("You clicked on SAVE and this file is selected " + test.FileName);
}
```

Note: usually you will work with the result and then doing your action rather than catching the `FileOk` event but it sounds like in this case you want to do that

Comment: Thanks a lot - very helpful - I need to stick with the Office (Word) dialog though, because if I create a new SaveFileDialog dialog, my namespace extension is not working properly.

Comment: Why? Note: I incorrectly wrote *your own* but I meant the standard .NET dialog.
Basically you use my code which uses the Windows SaveFileDialog, and I think that MS Office uses the same, set the Cancel = true and handle it in that method. There should not be any problem with namespace